# while true loop doesn't actually loop

Tags: python, function, while-loop

```
import random
def gen(): 
    return random.randrange(1, 10),random.randrange(1, 10)
def check_answer(numbers):   
    print("How much is", numbers[0], "times", numbers[1] ,'?') 
    product = int(input())
    while product != numbers[0]*numbers[1]:
        print("No.Please try again")
        product = int(input())
    print("Very good!") 
    return check_answer(numbers)
while True:
    gen()
    check_answer(gen())
```

I want to randomly generate two numbers to create a tuple and ask a question about the product of the two numbers. It should keep asking until the user gives the correct answer, and then I want a new question automatically asked. The two functions are doing just fine. Just the last step I couldn't get while True to call function gen() when "Very good" is printed. Thank you for your help!!!

Comment: What's the purpose of the first call to `gen()`?

Comment: "The two functions are doing just fine" is not quite right - you have question after all. And in addition to @Barmar question about first `gen()` call, what's the purpose of the recursive call to `check_answer()`with the return statement.

Comment: I just tried to delete the check_answer() part and it worked! Can you elaborate on why if I put it after return, it will keep calling check_answer with the same numbers? Thank you!!

Comment: What do you think `check_answer(numbers)` inside the function does if not call the function with the same numbers?

Answer (score 2):

1. Don't call extra `gen()` alone
2. Don't end `check_answer` by calling again `check_answer`, you cannot leave the method so, and with same numbers `check_answer(numbers)` you keep asking the same stuff (as you don't make any more call to `gen()`)

And you can directly put the text in the `input` method

```
def gen():
    return random.randrange(1, 10), random.randrange(1, 10)

def check_answer(numbers):
    product = int(input(f"How much is {numbers[0]} times {numbers[1]}: "))
    while product != numbers[0] * numbers[1]:
        product = int(input("No.Please try again: "))
    print("Very good!\n")

while True:
    check_answer(gen())
```

Comment: Ah! I get it now! Thanksss!!